# how to solve compose popup show over status bar or nav bar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I can't solve this problem that android compose.
Popup show over status bar or nav bar.
I want popup hide in status bar or nav bar with scroll.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    (1..50).forEach {
        Column {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        isVisible = !isVisible
                    },
                text = "test text $it"
            )

            if (it == 6 || it == 40) {
                val properties = PopupProperties(
                    clippingEnabled = false
                )

                Popup(
                    properties = properties
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color.Red),
                        text = "test popup"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aApvf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add padding for parent column, after adding padding your code will look like

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .padding(all = 25.dp)  // You can adjust padding according to requirement
    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
   (1..50).forEach {
       Column {
           Text(
               modifier = Modifier
                   .clickable {
                       isVisible = !isVisible
                   },
               text = "test text $it"
           )

           if (it == 6 || it == 40) {
               val properties = PopupProperties(
                   clippingEnabled = false
               )

               Popup(
                   properties = properties
               ) {
                   Text(
                       modifier = Modifier
                           .background(Color.Red),
                       text = "test popup"
                   )
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This should work for you.
Happy Coding..!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but, This is not working.